# How do I to iterate through a list from a REST call using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, restsharp

I'm relatively new to REST calls and am probably a beginner to intermediate in C#. I am trying to make a REST call to Qualys to obtain appliance information. My problem is that when I do a foreach loop to iterate through the List, the console app fails by just exiting after I input my credentials. I have verified that the API is accepting my credentials.

Bear in mind that I am connecting to Qualys using HttpBasicAuthenticator and I'm using a combination of RestSharp and XmlSerializer. I don't know if I'm doing this correctly, but here's what I got so far. I would like to use RestSharp completely, but I'm totally confused on what to do for the deserialization part, so I attempted to work on it with XmlSerializer using some examples from the Internet.

```
class Program
    {
        const string BaseUrl = "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/";        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
            Console.WriteLine("Username: ");
            var username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Password: ");
            var password = Console.ReadLine();

            var _client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
            _client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

            var request = new RestRequest("api/2.0/fo/appliance/", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "REST");
            request.AddParameter("action", "list");
            request.AddParameter("output_mode", "brief");
            var response = _client.Execute(request).Content;

            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "APPLIANCE_LIST_OUTPUT";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Appliance>), xRoot);
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(response);
            List<Appliance> applianceValues = (List<Appliance>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

            foreach (var i in applianceValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: " + i.ID);
                Console.WriteLine("UUID: " + i.UUID);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + i.NAME);
                Console.WriteLine("Software Version: " + i.SOFTWARE_VERSION);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + i.STATUS);
            }          
        }        
    }

 public class Appliance
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uuid")]
        public int UUID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "software_ver")]
        public int SOFTWARE_VERSION { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
    }
```

**Response: I got this response from commenting out the foreach loop and just doing**`Console.WriteLine(response);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE APPLIANCE_LIST_OUTPUT SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/appliance/appliance_list_output.dtd">
<APPLIANCE_LIST_OUTPUT>
  <RESPONSE>
    <DATETIME>2019-04-11T12:31:49Z</DATETIME>
    <APPLIANCE_LIST>
      <APPLIANCE>
        <ID>111111</ID>
        <UUID>1a2b3c4d-14qw-f00f-6744-g7455556bnf4</UUID>
        <NAME>My Appliance</NAME>
        <SOFTWARE_VERSION>2.6</SOFTWARE_VERSION>
        <RUNNING_SLICES_COUNT>0</RUNNING_SLICES_COUNT>
        <RUNNING_SCAN_COUNT>0</RUNNING_SCAN_COUNT>
        <STATUS>Online</STATUS>
      </APPLIANCE>
      <APPLIANCE>
        <ID>222222</ID>
        <UUID>bv51gh82-g496-88g8-8999-11abcd4567kk</UUID>
        <NAME>My Other Appliance</NAME>
        <SOFTWARE_VERSION>2.6</SOFTWARE_VERSION>
        <RUNNING_SLICES_COUNT>0</RUNNING_SLICES_COUNT>
        <RUNNING_SCAN_COUNT>0</RUNNING_SCAN_COUNT>
        <STATUS>Offline</STATUS>
      </APPLIANCE>
    </APPLIANCE_LIST>
  </RESPONSE>
</APPLIANCE_LIST_OUTPUT>
```

Right now my goal is just to output to the console a nice listing of some of the fields from the XML. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I've changed some values (ID, UUID, NAME) on response for confidentiality.**

Comment: Can you post a sample of the response string?  I need to see if it is consistent with your c# classes.

Comment: I've updated my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  It looks like you need to disable the DTD processing :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplianceOutput));
            ApplianceOutput applicance = (ApplianceOutput)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("APPLIANCE_LIST_OUTPUT")]
    public class ApplianceOutput
    {
        [XmlElement("RESPONSE")]
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
    public class Response
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("APPLIANCE_LIST")]
        [XmlArrayItem("APPLIANCE")]
        public List<Appliance> appliances { get; set; }
    }
    public class Appliance
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string UUID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string SOFTWARE_VERSION { get; set; }
        public int RUNNING_SLICES_COUNT { get; set; }
        public int RUNNING_SCAN_COUNT { get; set; }
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, it didn't work. I added the XML to the text.xml file. I then sent the output to ```Console.WriteLine(appliance);``` and received the following output: ```AutomateTickets.ApplianceOutput
Press any key to continue . . .```

Comment: I don't understand what you did.  the code posted works with your xml.  What does "I added the XML to the text.xml file" mean?  XML you can only have one Root element and appending xml files together doesn't work.

Comment: You defined the file as text.xml. I put the XML that would come from the call into that file in order to test this. How else would the XML get in there so the program can read the XML??

Comment: If you are getting the text in a response then just use string xml and you do not need to read from file.  appliance is a class so I do not know what you would get if you send a class object to Console.Writeline().  Writeline wants a string.